# Set a nameref variable as 'associative array' typeset

Tags: bash, associative-array

```
#declare -A var

function func {
local -n array=$1
array=([ci]=a [ca]=b [bo]=z)
}

func var 
echo ${var[@]}
```

This script works properly uncommenting the first line.
Unfortunately the typeset of the variable has to be conditionally decided inside the function.
Associative arrays don't seem to work properly if not declared explicitly.
Thanks

Comment: How does the function decide what type of array it is supposed to be creating? Can you show a more representative function?

Comment: The function parameters will be indexes and values of an array.
The function creates the array and return it through nameref variable.
If indexes are all numbers nameref will be a normal (indexed) array, otherwise associative.

Comment: Then I think you get to loop over your indices first and find out what type you have to make then use `declare -g -A $1` before you start assigning through the nameref. Though given this model of operation I wonder why you want the nameref here at all.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I understand that declaring variables inside or outside a function is not the same thing. The function is 20 lines and it will be used (source) in three different scripts. I like to use nameref to avoid forgotten variables wandering in the global space

Comment: If you want to keep a tight ship on global variables, you might take a look at the `DECLARATIVE_TEST_LEAKS` feature in [declarative.bash](https://github.com/threatgrid/declarative.bash/blob/master/declarative.bash) -- requiring global variable use to be declared, and with detection of names leaked into the global namespace by functions which do not declare them.