# Create and access the hash array in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, hash, nested

> Hi All,

Is it possible to use HashMap in Shell script just like in java.I am trying to find the  Hash Array to put the values as key and value again I need that array as value to the key in other HashMap.
ex.
Abc= A:3 B:6
PQR= N:8 Y:1 O:12

here I want Abc as a Hash Array with (Key,Val)=(A,3),(B,6) same for PQR again I want that Abc Hash Array as a value to Data as
Data (Key,Val)= ("Abc",$Abc)
("PQR",$PQR)

So later I can call the values of array by searching the "Abc" into Data and should get all the keyvalues of Abc.

Suppose I am calling from other sh file something like

Comp_Abc = get("Abc") and it should replace the values of Abc as

Comp_Abc = A:3 B:6

Can we do all these things in shell script.:) I hope someone had tried the same, please help me if it possible.

Thanks in Advance
Radha

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are called "associative arrays" in Bash, and were supported from version 4.0.  They are not supported by the standard POSIX shell.  Here is a quick example:

```
declare -A cities    # Required to declare 'cities' as an associative array

cities=([Australia]=Canberra,[Eire]=Dublin,[France]=Paris, 
        [Finland]=Helsinki,[UK]=London,[US]='Washington DC')
echo ${cities[UK]}

country=Iceland
cities[$country]=Reykjavik
```

As for nesting associative arrays, I can't say I have ever tried that, but you might be able to us a reference, see [Set a nameref variable as 'associative array' typeset - bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702860/set-a-nameref-variable-as-associative-array-typeset-bash)