# Pass variable name into function to test both existence and non-empty

Tags: bash

A) I am new to bash

B) My bash script sources a (user-editable) configuration script, where I want to use a function to test for variable existence and non-emptiness.

In my script, I have 21 lines (variables) each of this:

```
# check if constant exists
${_CONFIG_VERSION+"false"} && exitLogged "" "Constant _CONFIG_VERSION not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"
${_HOSTNAME+"false"} && exitLogged "" "Constant _HOSTNAME not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"
${_SYSTEM_NAME+"false"} && exitLogged "" "Constant _SYSTEM_NAME not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"
${_SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME+"false"} && exitLogged "" "Constant _SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"
...

# check if constant has a value
if [[ -z "${_CONFIG_VERSION}" ]]; then exitLogged "" "Constant _CONFIG_VERSION not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"; fi
if [[ -z "${_HOSTNAME}" ]]; then exitLogged "" "Constant _HOSTNAME not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"; fi
if [[ -z "${_SYSTEM_NAME}" ]]; then exitLogged "" "Constant _SYSTEM_NAME not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"; fi
if [[ -z "${_SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME}" ]]; then exitLogged "" "Constant _SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"; fi
...
```

... but wanted to do this:

```
checkIfExistAndNonEmpty _CONFIG_VERSION
checkIfExistAndNonEmpty _HOSTNAME
checkIfExistAndNonEmpty _SYSTEM_NAME
checkIfExistAndNonEmpty _SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME
```

... with function in **pseudo-code** like this:

```
function checkIfExistAndNonEmpty() {
    arg1=${1}
    "$"{$arg1+"false"} && exitLogged "" "Constant $arg1 not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"        
    if [[ -z "${arg1}" ]]; then ...; fi
}
```

exitLogged() records the two arguments ($LINENO $msg) passed in and exits.

Is such a function "checkIfExistAndNonEmpty()" even possible?

The intent is to pass the variable name; rebuild it into a variable I can test for existence and non-emptiness.

Usually if there is a repeat of the same thing then shove into a function... but I may ask for something that is not possible.

[edit 1]
I had a look at this... but do not really get it...

```
function checkIfExistAndNonEmpty() {
    suffix=$1
    echo "suffix:$suffix"
    declare prefix_$suffix=$1
    # ...and then...
    varname=prefix_$suffix
    echo "varname:${!varname}"
    echo "---"
}
```

[edit 2]
Upon reflection, I may be overthinking the solution to the problem?!
Maybe a simple

```
if [[ -z "${_variable}" ]]; then echo "Variable is not specified."; fi
```

... will do, as "unspecified" can mean 'it is empty' AND 'does not exist'.

So, unless some bright mind can enlighten me otherwise, I will go with my idea above. :)

Comment: `"$"{$arg1+"false"}` is an error, try https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Yes... why I said in "pseudo code"... :)

Comment: you want to use a `nameref` (aka `local -n ...`); see the sample code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593740) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702860); while those questions are dealing with arrays the main step is the same, eg, 'local -n arg1=${1}`

Comment: i had a look, and the misunderstanding seems to be that I want the variable name. Yes, I want the variable name and the variable itself (to check if exists). Hence the idea to pass the name and then check for THE variable's existence; that measn I have to convert the name to a the actual variable.

Answer (score 1):

Possible to rephrase the question into the following: At a specific point of the code, the script has to check that a list of variables had been set to non-null values.

Consider to option to achieve this, without lot of copy/paste: using the bash built-in :?, or using custom iteration

Using bash `:?` operator, you will get the bash standard error message + exit status:

- message "bash: VARIABLE: parameter null or not set
- Exit status of 1

Possible to specify more than one test per line.

```
: ${_CONFIG_VERSION:?}
: ${_HOSTNAME:?}
: ${_SYSTEM_NAME:?} ${_SP_LINK_CFG_FILENAME:?}
```

If important to control error message, or have custom error handling

```
v_list=( _CONFIG_VERSION _HOSTNAME _SYSTEM_NAME ...)
for v in "${v_list[@]}" ; do
    # Check if the variable expand to non-empty
    if [ ! -n "${!v}" ] ; then
       exitLogged "Constant $v not set in ${_CONFIG_FILE}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Yes, this certainly simplifies the non-empty check; thanks :) but does not clarify, whether I can actually turn a variable name back into a variable to check for its existence.

Comment: Just implemented it, nice, and figured "${v[@]}" shoudl be "${v_list[@]}"